# Android App Crash on CkFtp2 class from Chilkat library

Tags: android, java-native-interface, chilkat

I'm developing and Android app, that uses FTP comunication, and just randomly, i get this error, without trace to my actual code or any execution coded by me.

I cannot reproduce the crash, and i don't know when it happens or why.

This is the error i get:

```
Fatal Exception: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: com.chilkatsoft.CkFtp2.finalize() timed out after 10 seconds
   at com.chilkatsoft.chilkatJNI.delete_CkFtp2(chilkatJNI.java)
   at com.chilkatsoft.CkFtp2.delete(CkFtp2.java:32)
   at com.chilkatsoft.CkFtp2.finalize(CkFtp2.java:25)
   at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize(Daemons.java:229)
   at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.run(Daemons.java:207)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

I have Fabric's Crashlytics and this is what it shows me:

[image]

Again, no trace to my code or anything coded by me at all, so i literally dont know why my app is crashing.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the crash can happen if the JVM garbage collection takes too long.

In this case, you are cleaning up a CkFtp2 object instance. If the CkFtp2 object had a connection to an FTP server, then the connection is closed in the object destructor.  If the connection as TLS, then the TLS session is cleanly closed.  (Also the TCP socket connection is cleanly closed.) This could cause a delay if the response time from the server is not fast.  Make sure each CkFtp2 object's connection is explicitly closed by calling CkFtp2.Disconnect() prior to removing your last reference from the object instance.  That may solve the problem because once disconnected, there is no connection to close.

The other possibility has to do with background threads and async.  For example, let's say you start an async operation -- such as calling GetFileAsync.   You then remove your last reference to the CkFtp2 object and the Java garbage collection decides to cleanup the object.  The Java garbage collector doesn't know there is another native reference to the object that is doing the async operation.  It tries to delete the native object, but must wait to obtain an internal "critical section".  Thus the garbage collector is stuck waiting for the async operation to complete, and that would be the cause.  You don't want to remove your last Java reference while an async operation is running.  Keep at least one Java reference to the object until the async operation is finished.